# \IfStrEqCase issue using \csname

Tags: macros, conditionals, etoolbox

I want to use `\csname` inside `\IfStrEqCase` but I have an error. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forloop}

%dados-a
\newcommand {\auxsistelet}[3]{\IfStrEq{#2}{BICICLETA}{\IfStrEqCase{#1}    {{}{Seus sistemas de segurança para o tráfego (freio e direção) atuavam a     contento}{n}{Seus componentes de segurança para o tráfego (direção e     freio) não puderam ser testados devido à magnitude dos danos ocasionados     pelo acidente}}[Seus sistemas de segurança para o tráfego (freio e     direção) atuavam a contento, excetuando-se #1, face aos danos sofridos no     evento]
}{
\IfStrEqCase{#1}{{}{Seus sistemas de segurança para o tráfego (freio,     direção e elétrico) atuavam a contento}{n}{Seus componentes de segurança     para o tráfego (direção, freio e elétrico) não puderam ser testados devido     à magnitude dos danos ocasionados pelo acidente}}[\IfStrEq{#1}{chave}    {\IfStrEq{#3}{s}{Seus componentes de segurança para o tráfego (direção,     freio) funcionavam a contento. O sistema elétrico não pôde ser testado     devido à ausência da chave do referido veículo}{Seus componentes de     segurança para o tráfego (direção, freio e elétricos) não puderam ser     testados devido à ausência da chave do referido veículo. Da mesma forma,     fica prejudicada a análise de sua porção interna}}{Seus sistemas de     segurança para o tráfego (freio, direção e elétricos) atuavam a contento,     excetuando-se #1, face aos danos sofridos no evento}]}.}

%dados
\newcommand \placa {AAA-0000}
\newcommand \eletrico{\sistelet{n}\\}
\newcommand \tipoveiculo {AUTOMÓVEL}
\newcommand \moto {n}

\newcommand \placab {BBB-0000}
\newcommand \eletricob{\sisteletb{}\\}
\newcommand \tipoveiculob {MOTOCICLETA}
\newcommand \motob {s}

\begin{document}

\ifdef{\placa}{\newcommand \sistelet[1]{\auxsistelet{#1}{\tipoveiculo}    {\moto}}}{}
\ifdef{\placab}{\newcommand \sisteletb[1]{\auxsistelet{#1}    {\tipoveiculob}{\motob}}}{}

% \foreach \x in {b,...,e}{
% \ifcsdef{placa\x}{\expandafter\global\newcommand \csname sistelet\x\endcsname[1]{\csname auxsistelet\x\endcsname{#1}{\csname     tipoveiculo\x\endcsname}{\csname moto\x\endcsname}}}{}
% }

\ifdef{\eletrico}{\eletrico}{}
\ifdef{\eletricob}{\eletricob}{}
\end{document}
```

I want to change this:

```
\ifdef{\placab}{\newcommand \sisteletb[1]{\auxsistelet{#1}    {\tipoveiculob}{\motob}}}{}
```

For something like this:

```
\foreach \x in {b,...,e}{
\ifcsdef{placa\x}{\expandafter\global\newcommand \csname sistelet\x\endcsname[1]{\csname auxsistelet\x\endcsname{#1}{\csname     tipoveiculo\x\endcsname}{\csname moto\x\endcsname}}}{}
}
```

How can I do this?? Help me!

Comment: Perhaps you should explain first what your real intentions are here. I see a bunch of `\csname...\endcsname` and (most probably) wrongly placed `}`

Comment: I want to make a code for to be better than create multilines for \placab \placac \placad and \placae

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you are trying to do but `\expandafter\global\newcommand` is wrong and you probably wanted `\global\expandafter\newcommand\csname...\endcsname[1]{...}`, but that can't work either because `\newcommand` checks non expandably for various things and the `\global` will be without effect. But

```
\long\global\expandafter\def\csname...\endcsname #1{...}
```

works. As I commented at your other question [how to use a \global \foreach?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302718/how-to-use-a-global-foreach), you can use `\csgdef` as you already load `etoolbox`. Or, without package, as you are using LaTeX:

```
\makeatletter
\long\global\@namedef{...}#1{...}
\makeatother
```

If used within macros replace `#1` in the definitions above by `##1`. (and the `\makeatletter/\makeatother` pair must not be inside the macro but surround it).

Comment: the use case was and still is far from clear, but an addendum must be made: an `\x` from a TikZ `\foreach` loop will not be expanded in time if it occurs in the replacement text of the defined macro. As pointed out by @PeterGrill http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302718/how-to-use-a-global-foreach#comment733854_302718, something like `\csxdef` is probably needed. With the suitable `\noexpand`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by this way:

```
\ifdef{\placa}{\newcommand \sistelet[1]{\auxsistelet{#1}{\tipoveiculo}{\moto}}}{}
\ifnumcomp{\nveics}{>}{1}{
\foreach \x in {b,...,\alphalph{\nveics}}{
\ifcsdef{placa\x}{\csgdef{sistelet\x}##1{\auxsistelet{##1}{tipoveiculo\x}{moto\x}}}{}
}
}{}
```

Comment: Indeed of posting a self-answer you should rather accept jfbu's answer who pointed you into the right direction with `\csgdef` etc.

Comment: are you sure this works? the `\x` from `tipoveiculo\x` will not be expanded by the `\csgdef`. This was pointed out by @PeterGrill http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302718/how-to-use-a-global-foreach#comment733854_302718