# how to use a \global \foreach?

Tags: macros, foreach

Is it possible to make a global foreach? How is the correct way to define arguments inside a \csdef command?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,hidelinks]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forloop}

%dados-a
\newcommand {\auxsistelet}[3]{\IfStrEq{#2}{BICICLETA}{\IfStrEqCase{#1}    {{}{Seus sistemas de segurança para o tráfego (freio e direção) atuavam a     contento}{n}{Seus componentes de segurança para o tráfego (direção e     freio) não puderam ser testados devido à magnitude dos danos ocasionados     pelo acidente}}[Seus sistemas de segurança para o tráfego (freio e     direção) atuavam a contento, excetuando-se #1, face aos danos sofridos no     evento]
}{
\IfStrEqCase{#1}{{}{Seus sistemas de segurança para o tráfego (freio,     direção e elétrico) atuavam a contento}{n}{Seus componentes de segurança     para o tráfego (direção, freio e elétrico) não puderam ser testados devido     à magnitude dos danos ocasionados pelo acidente}}[\IfStrEq{#1}{chave}    {\IfStrEq{#3}{s}{Seus componentes de segurança para o tráfego (direção,     freio) funcionavam a contento. O sistema elétrico não pôde ser testado     devido à ausência da chave do referido veículo}{Seus componentes de     segurança para o tráfego (direção, freio e elétricos) não puderam ser     testados devido à ausência da chave do referido veículo. Da mesma forma,     fica prejudicada a análise de sua porção interna}}{Seus sistemas de     segurança para o tráfego (freio, direção e elétricos) atuavam a contento,     excetuando-se #1, face aos danos sofridos no evento}]}.}

%dados
\newcommand \placa {AAA-0000}
\newcommand \eletrico{\sistelet{n}\\}
\newcommand \tipoveiculo {AUTOMÓVEL}
\newcommand \moto {n}

\newcommand \placab {BBB-0000}
\newcommand \eletricob{\sisteletb{n}\\}
\newcommand \tipoveiculob {MOTOCICLETA}
\newcommand \motob {s}

\begin{document}

\ifdef{\placa}{\newcommand \sistelet[1]{\auxsistelet{#1}{\tipoveiculo}{\moto}}}{}

\foreach \x in {b,...,e}{
\ifcsdef{placa\x}{

\global\csdef{sistelet\x}#1{\auxsistelet{##1}{\csname     tipoveiculo\x\endcsname}{\csname moto\x\endcsname}}
}{}
}

\ifdef{\eletrico}{\eletrico}{}
\ifdef{\eletricob}{\eletricob}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You don't seem to use `\global\foreach` ? And you don't say what the problem is ....

Comment: I want to define a global command inside a \foreach, this is the problem:

     \global\csdef{sistelet\x}#1{\auxsistelet{##1}{\csname     tipoveiculo\x\endcsname}{\csname moto\x\endcsname}}

Comment: But what is the command supposed to do? At the first iteration, for example, what should the definition be?

Comment: why use a loop that uses a group? if you did that  you would not need global, also you are defining all your commands in terms of `\x` so they would all have the same value. It would help if you said what the intention of this code is?

Comment: The intention in this code is in the future to create more of these:
\ifdef{\eletricob}{\eletricob}{}
\ifdef{\eletricoc}{\eletricoc}{}
\ifdef{\eletricod}{\eletricod}{}

and I want to call \sisteletX outside the foreach loop (X being b, c, d...)

Comment: but what do you want  `\sisteleta`, `\ \sisteletb` etc to be defined to be? currently you are suggesting that they all have definition `\csdef{sistelet\x}#1{\auxsistelet{##1}{\csname     tipoveiculo\x\endcsname}{\csname moto\x\endcsname}}`  which means they all have identical definition. If you want \x to expand before making the definition you need different code but hard to guess really/

Comment: \sistelet is \auxsistelet{#1}{\tipoveiculo}{\moto}
I am solving using \begingroup and \endgroup and a \foreach inside the group

Comment: If you are having trouble defining a loop command, explaining the problem in terms of that same problematic loop command is not (always going to be) particularly illuminating to others. Can you describe what you are trying to achieve in pseudocode or some other relatively straightforward code?

Comment: I typed `texdoc etoolbox` then I searched for  `csdef` in the PDF viewer, and I see the explanations there relative to `\csdef` and right below it there is a `\csgdef` which is said to make global definitions.

Comment: @jfbu: Probably need the `csxdef` to ensure that the loop parameter is expanded.

Comment: @PeterGrill right, and a `\noexpand` then before the mysterious `\auxsistelet` using non-expandable `\IfStrEq`.

Comment: Solved by this way:

\ifdef{\placa}{\newcommand \sistelet[1]{\auxsistelet{#1}{\tipoveiculo}{\moto}}}{}
\ifnumcomp{\nveics}{>}{1}{
\foreach \x in {b,...,\alphalph{\nveics}}{
\ifcsdef{placa\x}{\csgdef{sistelet\x}##1{\auxsistelet{##1}{tipoveiculo\x}{moto\x}}}{}
}
}{}

I until didn't know how gcsdef works, because using \alphalph gives me an error.